# How to add thymeleaf variable in js

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

I want to add row in table and the option value do not show anything when I use th:text. For the varaible, it links with message.properties, which include different languages.

```
function addCompanyApp() {
    var rowCount = $("#table_companyAppList tr").length;
    if (rowCount < 9) {

        var newRow = "<tr class='tablerow'>"
                
    
                +"<td>"
                +"<select id='cAptTitle' name='cAptTitle' required>"
                +" <option value='none' th:text='#{application5}' selected></option>"
                +"<option value='Mr.' th:text='#{application6}' ></option>"
                +"<option value='Mrs.' th:text='#{application7}'></option>"
                +"<option value='Miss' th:text='#{application8}' ></option>" 
                +" </select>"
                +" </td>"
                + "<td><input id='cAptNameEng' name='cAptNameEng' type='text' style='min-width:15em;background: #FFFFFF;border-radius: 0.5em;'></td>"
                + "<td><input id='cAptNameChi' name='cAptNameChi'type='text' style='min-width:15em;background: #FFFFFF;border-radius: 0.5em;' ></td>"
                + "<td><input id='cAptHkid'name='cAptHkid' type='text' style='min-width:15em;background: #FFFFFF;border-radius: 0.5em;' pattern='[A-Z]\d{4}'></td>"
                + "<td><input id='cAptPost'name='cAptPost' type='text' style='min-width:15em;background: #FFFFFF;border-radius: 0.5em;'></td>"
                + "</tr>";

        $("#table_companyAppList tbody").append(newRow);
    } else {
        alert("Maximum 8 participants.");
    }
}
```